# Trying to get 3 finger gestures. Geis tools shows only 2 finger support when I've used 3 on Windows 7 partition

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, touchegg

I've been trying to get touchegg to work so I can have 3 finger gestures similar to that on a MacBook. It wasn't working so I checked geis-tools for how many fingers are supported. It says 2 but then I realized I've used 3 when I use my windows 7 partition. Anybody know what the issue is? 
I'm on 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try again the touchegg, by now (13.04) it is only needed to install it with no further configuration, except for the definition of the gestures you like. Please take a look in this blog post: http://task3.cc/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/